# Large purple thing around object

Tags: cycles-render-engine, objects, shaders

I purchased a rigged hand and when I use cycles it appears with this large purple thing around it and I have no idea what it is?

I've attached an image of it in cycles and in eevee.[image: object in eevee]
[image: object in cycles]

Comment: That's the colour which blender displays on an object if it can't find the colour texture that is supposed to be on it.

Comment: Yep, but I'm not sure what the object is as it isn't there in eevee

Comment: If the material uses displacement it could be acting funny because of the missing texture

Comment: Ah yes it was a displacement problem, thank you